# How to perform keyboard shortcuts like Ctrl+I for italics or Ctrl+U for underlining in LyX?

Tags: lyx, bold, italic

Every time I try to use the aforementioned keyboard shortcuts, LyX says "Command Disabled". How do I activate these shortcuts?

Comment: Note that "e" is used because it stands for "emphasize", which you can think of as an abstraction of "italicize".

Comment: Incidentally, I believe that Ctrl-e and Ctrl+u are the default keystrokes bound to the font-emph and font-underline actions.  So you could just use those shortcuts instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> may be set to "inset-toggle" which in regular use doesn't apply, while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> *should* be set to "font-underline" (as is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd>).

You are able to change the key binding sequences to suit your needs. Under Tools > Preferences > Editing > Shortcuts, activate the keys that you're interested in using as shortcut combinations. Specifically, find "font-ital" and "font-underline" under *Font, Layouts and Textclasses*:

[image]

If a bind is already used elsewhere, you can overwrite this to suit your personal needs.

Comment: Do you have any advice if the above method doesn't work? I'm trying to map `Ctrl+1` to "layout Chapter" but get "Command disabled" even after removing the previous binding.

Comment: _(I've managed to get it working with `Alt+1`, still curious why it didn't work with Ctrl)_