# Normal italics in LyX

Tags: lyx

My friend is using LyX for a course's assignment, and neither she nor I know how to get normal `\itshape` italics in LyX: all we know is how to get `\mathit`. So how do you get `\itshape` (besides using TeX code)?

Comment: Does ctrl + e do you what you want? If curious to learn more, search for something like "LaTeX emphasis italics".

Comment: @scottkosty Yes it does.

Comment: good to know. This question might be a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/206721/how-to-perform-keyboard-shortcuts-like-ctrli-for-italics-or-ctrlu-for-underlin . Also, you might be interested in Werner's the explanation here of why it is called "emphasize" instead of "italics": http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/what-exactly-are-the-semantics-of-noun-case/117101#117101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the toolbar, there is an item with an icon containing a bold a on the BL corner and an italic b in the TR, behind the a. Click there, and there is a Series menu which has Bold Medium and another option, and a Shape menu with Italics as options. Actually I haven't checked there is that option, I found that panel for size and saw it had Bold. Also, for Italics there is another item saying «Commuta stile enfasi», which translates to something like «Commute emphasis style», which changes from normal to italics and vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

You can mark the corresponding text, `right click -> Text Style -> Customized` and choose `Italic` under `Shape`

Comment: The dialog box this opens is the same as the button I describe in my answer.